# Calculating display coordinates for the horizon given the camera position and forward, up and right unit vectors

Tags: math, vector, 3d, plane, rotational-matrices

I've written a simple roller coaster simulator in [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/) using 3d catmull-rom splines to create the track layout. Rotation minimizing frames are calculated so that surface normals flow smoothly throughout the spline. The camera path is pre-calculated with a look-at rotation matrix for each position (using unit normals for the direction of travel, the surface normal of the track and the cross product of the two. This all works fine and can be viewed [here](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/364502191).

I'd like to add a simple background where anything above the horizon is blue for sky and anything below is green for land but am hitting a complete mental block on how to calculate this. I suspect I should consider the horizon as a simple 3D plane with surface normal of (0,1,0), rotate that using the look-at matrix and then create the visible horizon coordinates from the result but need some help in how to do this.

Any suggestions would be very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it by rotating the position of the horizon (0,0,0) relative to the camera and the plane's normal using the look-at matrix. It was then just a case of projecting a distant point on the horizon onto the screen.